# Finding Xth term of a series

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have a simple problem.

I am having an array A[] of N numbers. I have to perform this operarion:

```
for(i = 2; i<=N; i++)
    A[i] = A[i] + A[i-1]
```

to the array A[] k times. And after performing this operation k times, I have to output the Xth index element.

Doing it with brute force, will lead to TLE.

I was searching for some pattern, but, I came to a solution which is not perfect as it needs to be.

Can you please help me, to find some more efficient solution to this problem.

I have an example, to clear the question.

Let's say array `A` is `[1,2,3]` and I need to perform the above operation 3 times then:

Array after 1st turn: `A=[1,3,6]`
Array after 2nd turn: `A=[1,4,10]`
Array after 3rd turn: `A=[1,5,15]`

So, if I am required to find the 2nd element of the array now, then it would be 5.

Comment: Have you looked at Pascal's triangle?

Comment: Is this a programming competition that you try to cheat? If not, please post the link to the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is most probably a programming competition.

Comment: Does the array always start with an increasing sequence, 1,2,3,4,..?

Comment: @SalvadorDali Questions aren't off-topic just because they come from a programming competition.

Comment: @Sneftel based on my understanding asking people to solve an ongoing programming competition for you is not a good idea. Wait till it will finish and then post your question.

Answer (score 1):

I you look to the Pascal's triangle (as @MBo say) you may notice that after k times the number of times each number get added in the final result is equal to a square in the triangle following the diagonals. Let see an example here:

[image]

This image correspond to iterate four times for the first three elements. So, as you can see if we have as input `k` equal to the number of times and `n` equal to the index of the element to return, all we have to do is multiply each of the numbers in the diagonal filled in blue until the red line (the image configuration correspond to `k = 4` and `n = 2`).

After that, we have this formula:

[image]

Now, to improve the way we calculate the formula show above, we can use dynamic programming and calculate the factorial function from 0 ... k+n (note that the bigger number in the sequence is k-1+n). With this we can access to `factorial(n)` in a constant time. Also if we expand the combinatoric factor inside the summation we notice that the factor `(k - 1 + i - i)! = (k - 1)!` so, we can put this outside the summation.

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int findingXth(int a[], int n, int k, int factorial[]){

    if (k == 0)
        return a[n];

    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        int up = k - 1 + i;
        result += (factorial[up] / factorial[i]) * a[n - i];
    }
    return result / factorial[k - 1];
}

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int n = 2;
    int k = 3;

    int factorial[100000]; // probably the expecification of the problem has some upper bounds for n and k (the length of the factorial array can be set to n+k+1);
    factorial[0] = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < n + k; i++)
    {
        factorial[i] = factorial[i - 1] * i;
    }

    int result = findingXth(a, n, k, factorial);

    std::cout << result;

    return 0;
}
```